# How to produce a circular shift with postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's suppose that I have this simple table:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

If I do:

```
WITH example AS
(
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3,4]) as ID
)
SELECT ID, lAG(ID,1) over() as LAG_ID 
FROM example
-- The shift is 1 in this case, but could be any integer in practice.
```

I got:

| ID | LAG_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

But I need a **circular** shift:

| ID | LAG_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **4** |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

Is there an elegant way to produce this result ?

Comment: Little trick on the side: to generate a list of numbers, `generate_series(1,4)` is more flexible then unnesting an array

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the little trick, indeed easier to read and more flexible.

Comment: Why `over()` without `order by` ? What is the intended order?

Comment: @Serg I'm just trying to produce the simplest possible example and since the table is already sorted I've not added an `order by` clause. The intended order is `over(order by ID  asc)`.

Comment: Is ID nullable ?

Comment: @Serg No, in my case ID is not nullable. I've already tried to use `coalesc()` but I've only  found a solution that require to duplicate the original table with a reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

If ID is not nullable

```
WITH example AS
(
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3,4]) as ID
)
SELECT ID, coalesce(lAG(ID,1) over(order by ID asc), (select max(ID) from example)) as LAG_ID 
FROM example
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatelly there is a small comment in my question that indicate that the shift is not necessary `1` but could be any integer.

Comment: But with `coalesc` I can do `SELECT ID, COALESCE (LAG(ID,1) OVER(), LEAD(id,(SELECT max(ID)-1 FROM example)) over())` which solve my question